# Android: How can I prevent MediaPlayer from playing overlapping audio?

Tags: android, audio

I'm building a thug life sound effect player and I wanted to know how can I stop the MediaPlayer from playing 2 or more tracks the same time.

This is the method that's called when a button is clicked:

```
    int sequence = 1;
public void thugPlay (View view) {
            // assign a media player to an audio file
    MediaPlayer nothingButThatGthang = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.g_thang);
    MediaPlayer nextEpisode = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.next_episode);
    MediaPlayer fuckThePolice = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ftp);
    MediaPlayer hipnotize = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.hipnotize);
    MediaPlayer moveBitch = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.move_bitch);
    MediaPlayer ridin = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ridin);
    MediaPlayer still = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.still);
            // Plays according to sequence's value
    if (sequence == 1) {
        still.stop();
        nothingButThatGthang.start();
        sequence++ ;
    }
    else if (sequence == 2) {
        nothingButThatGthang.stop();
        nextEpisode.start();
        sequence++ ;
    }
    else if (sequence == 3) {
        nextEpisode.stop();
        fuckThePolice.start();
        sequence++ ;
    }
    else if (sequence == 4) {
        fuckThePolice.stop();
        hipnotize.start();
        sequence++ ;
    }
    else if (sequence == 5) {
        hipnotize.stop();
        moveBitch.start();
        sequence++ ;
    }
    else if (sequence == 6) {
        moveBitch.stop();
        ridin.start();
        sequence++ ;
    }
    else {
        ridin.stop();
        still.start();
        sequence = 1 ;
    }
}
```

As you can see, before playing the current audio file it should stop the previous one, however, it doesn't happen.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one MediaPlayer variable as class member:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

Then in your click event:

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
}

if (sequence == 1) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.still);
        mp.start();
        sequence++;
    }
```

You should off-course complete the If statment.

Comment: Took me a while but I managed to implement this in the code. Toda Gever